# Is it faster to level up in COD: Ghosts in Multiplayer or Squad mode?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

From what I can tell, Squads and multiplayer both allow you to level up your COD characters.  Squads allows you to play with all of your characters, but with multiplayer you have to choose a character.

If I'm trying to level up as fast as possible, which mode provides the most rank/XP per match?  Does squads allow multiple characters to level up simultaneously?

Comment: In squads it has a set limit on the amount of XP you can get in one game so I wouldn't recommend playing it to level up quickly. (2,000 xp per game I think)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that Multiplayer levels you up more, the reason is because in Squads you reach a certain amount of XP and then stop leveling up in each game you play.

Comment: if all you wanna do is level up quick squads then quit the game when you hit the max xp and restart another game do it over and over, if you have double xp doing then its even faster

Answer (score 0):

If you play strikezone 24/7 you have a choice of 3 game modes kill confirmed,domination, TDM. If you play domination it would give you the most amount of xp, if you want more kills to get xp play squad mode, but when you reach the maximum amount of xp 2,000 I think, it says a message XP REACHED,finish the game and then back out the game and start up the mode again, then keep going so I think if you get 2,000 xp per game consistently you should rank up pretty fast and it's more fun because you can get more kills on bots.

Answer (score -2):

I've found that Domination has personally yielded me more XP per game than any other game mode.

Comment: if ur skilled I would go with Search & Destroy. Drops more XP.